# Difference between LRW and XEX modes

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, tweakable-cipher

LRW and XEX modes of operation look similar. They are both tweakable narrow-block encryption with XORs before and after each single-block cipher.

I didn't really get the point where they differ or why one would be better than the other.

What I currently understand (could be wrong):

- LRW: `E_K1(P+K2*I)+K2*I`
- XEX: `E_K1(P+K2*2^I)+K2*2^I`

LRW could be a problem if plaintext contains `0||K2`, allowing an attacker to discover `K2`.

Questions:

1. What kind of security could be compromised if `K2` is discovered? It kinds of tells you some input-output pairs about the AES box, but not on the provided plaintext. Not sure what is the formal security notion about this.
2. Can I assume the tweak method (`K2*I` vs `K2*2^I`) is the only difference between LRW and XEX?

Comment: They are not encryption algorithms. They are block cipher mode of operation.

Comment: The difference is the tweak methods and the problems; [LRW issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_P1619#LRW_issue) and [XEX issue](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-74462-7_8.pdf)

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you, I edited the question with information from your link. Most citations about the problem in your link are broken, though.

Comment: I did find some problems with LRW in the links, but I could not find much on XEX.